# Field Value Not Showing

Tags: page-layout, contact

I have an issue viewing the phone field on the contact object. There is a value for phone on both the account and contact. I can prove this by pulling both fields in a report, on a given record. The field is also on both page layouts. Both the field and value can be seen on the account. However, on the contact you can see the field, but not the value. I have checked field level security and field accessibility but nothing. There are also no field dependencies. Account owner is the same as the contact owner and my OWD is set to public.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working through a case with Salesforce I have confirmed the answer to this issue. Phone on the contact object was actually blank. The catch is that if you run a contact report and the phone field is blank on the contact, it will populate that field with the value of the phone number on the account...for that report (since it is the parent object).

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you have renamed any of the Phone fields so their labels duplicate and you're in fact looking at wrong one? (AssistantPhone, HomePhone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone, Phone + any custom one you might have).

If you edit that record - is the field editable? Does it have `name="con10"`?

Does it happen for all contacts or only this one?

Have you tried in different browsers? Maybe you have plugins like Skype that try to be helpful and something goes wrong there...

Comment: All good ideas, but no luck. The field I'm using is the standard phone field on the contact object so I can't rename it. It is happening to all records and across all browsers. I am able to edit the field. When I inspect the element I see the field name as "id=con10_ileinner'

Comment: Including the `con10` check? Magic. I guess you'll have to contact support... WHat about if you search for that phone in the sidebar or chatter's global search? Also - are you on eu1 or na8? I think there are some major performance issues today (http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status), maybe something is not being indexed nicely... Was the contact loaded recently or does it affect all of them?